# How to create a nodejs AWS lambda function locally using vscode and not serverless or SAM CLI?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I've go through hundreds of blogs/videos/resources but nowhere it mentions how to create a simple lambda function for Nodejs REST API locally using vscode, AWS toolkit extension and AWS cli. Is there any way where I can create a simple nodejs endpoint on my local and run using above and not serverless or SAM?( There's some internal restrictions hence I can't use them)

Comment: When you say "REST API", do you mean you also want to run AWS API Gateway locally? Or do you just want to run the Lambda locally and use the AWS CLI lambda invoke function to invoke your Lambda?

Comment: Hi @Jens, so I want to create a nodejs route that calls a rest api endpoint and returns a json object. Eg. If I request https://localhost:8080/api/getCountry, then in the code via axios I'll be calling a 3rd party API. It's very simple in Node application. Now that I want to convert this into a lambda function, how can I do that locally and not AWS console with some button clicks. Also with debugging capabilities in vscode.? I have AWS access, AWS toolkit, CLI, but still idk how to go ahead. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set up a API gateway and event trigger for your lambda that triggers whenever a HTTP request comes in. So here are steps

1. Look into [serverless framwork](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway) where you will define a serverless.yaml file that will have configuration to mention how your lambda will get invoked (In this case, its a HTTP event)
2. In your IDE of choice, use [serverless-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline) npm package
3. Your IDE config will look something like this (This example uses IntelliJ IDE)
   [IDE config to start up Lambda in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxJ1E.png)
4. Once you start up the service in local, you should be able to hit the REST endpoint in local using any rest client like Postman
5. Instead of (4) above you could also directly invoke your lambda function in local using AWS CLI like `aws lambda invoke /dev/null \ --endpoint-url http://localhost:3002 \ --function-name <Your lambda function name> \ --payload '{<Your payload>}'`